# Same method for multiple classes in R

Tags: r

I often encounter scenarios where I wish to have the same method for two classes, when they are similar enough. For example:

```
func.matrix = function(m) {
stopifnot(ncol(m) == 2)
c(mean(m[, 1]), sd(m[, 2]))
}

func.data.frame = function(m) {
stopifnot(ncol(m) == 2)
c(mean(m[, 1]), sd(m[, 2]))
}
```

How can I save the redundancy?

Comment: Is everything else the same in `func.matrix` and `func.data.frame`? Or just one step in the function? Can you be a little more specific about the scenarios you often run into?

Comment: Yeah, everything is the same for these two functions.

Comment: `func.matrix <- func.data.frame <- function(m) { ...`?

Comment: Say we have two classes and we take the greatest common part, and make a function for that part.

Comment: Ah! This is so cool! I wonder how I could fail to realize that... :D Thanks!

Comment: Also, what about `function.default` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both functions are actually the same, then you can do something like this to save yourself some typing at least:

```
func.matrix <- func.data.frame <- function(m) {
  stopifnot(ncol(m) == 2)
  c(mean(m[, 1]), sd(m[, 2]))
}
func.matrix
# function(m) {
# stopifnot(ncol(m) == 2)
# c(mean(m[, 1]), sd(m[, 2]))
# }
func.data.frame
# function(m) {
# stopifnot(ncol(m) == 2)
# c(mean(m[, 1]), sd(m[, 2]))
# }
```

The other alternative, as you mentioned in the comment, would be to move the common part out into a function of its own (refactoring, I guess it's called?) and call that within your functions.

Comment: +1.  Also, this is a great example of the difference between `=` and `<-`

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work within an R package though: roxygen would only recognise and export the first method. The other functions would be available via `package:::`, but not exported